# ReferenceError: nlapiLoadFile is not defined error In Netsuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to run a simple script that loads a json file and gets the contents of the file. However, the first line of the script already sends an error saying that a function from the SuiteScript API is not defined.
'**ReferenceError: nlapiLoadFile is not defined**' is what I'm getting.

```
function pageInit(context) {

        var File = nlapiLoadFile('/SuiteScripts/jsonfile.json');
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
   }
```

I'm thinking there might be a problem with my account because I had a similar problem with SuiteScript 2.0 where the entire File module was missing in the API on my account. That is why I'm using 1.0 as shown above.

Comment: FWIW, You could modify the JSON file to assign the contents to a variable(effectively turning it into a javascript file), and add the file as a library to the client script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're trying to call this in pageInit(), I'll assume that you're creating a client script.  `nlapiLoadFile()` is not available in client scripts.  According to the help file for that function:  This API is supported in server-side scripts.

Comment: Ohh I see. Is there a type that is recommended when loading files?

Comment: See my comment on the main question for a quick/dirty solution. Otherwise, you could convert the script to a UserEvent script (beforeLoad) which executes server-side and thus has access to the LoadFile api. Though the specifics of what you're trying to accomplish may require both a user event and client script I guess.

Comment: @SheaBrennan a user event script works for me. I have some other errors now but I think I can take it from there. You're right, I might need a client script but not so sure yet. I just want to read the json file then upload the contents to records.

Answer (score 0):

For me issue was SuitScript Version. My script was originally in SuiteScript 2.0 but later I changed to 1.0 and then it worked fine.